# Constructing quaternions - proof that square of each imaginary unit is -1

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions, invariant-theory

During construction of vector space of quaternions over real numbers I encountered a problem that I can't quite put my finger on.

For the context: Hamilton a multiplication in plane that keeps preservation of length. Now he's would like to find something similar in 3 dimension but instead concludes couple things.

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Euclidean space consisting of vectors $\mathbf x=\left\langle x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}\right\rangle^T$, with $\mathbf x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. This is a vector space, and as such has the standard addition of vectors and multiplication by scalar. It also has scalar product 
$$
\mathbf {\color {red}a} \cdot \mathbf {\color {blue}b} =\sum _{i=0}^{n-1}{\color {red}a}_{i}{\color {blue}b}_{i}={\color {red}a}_{1}{\color {blue}b}_{1}+{\color {red}a}_{2}{\color {blue}b}_{2}+\cdots +{\color {red}a}_{n}{\color {blue}b}_{n},
$$

euclidean norm, and a standard basis $E=\{e_0,\dots,e_{n-1}\}$ where $e_i$ has a $1$ as its $i$th entry and $0$s elsewhere. Note that by this definition, $e_0$ has all $0$ entries.

Now we define multiplication as follows:

Multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a morphism $m:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$  that satisfies:

(i) is bilinear

(ii) has multiplicative unit $e_0$ that $e_0\mathbf x=\mathbf xe_0=\mathbf x$ for any vector $\mathbf x$ of our vector space.

Finally my question:

If we were to add third property to multiplication, that is the preservation of distances mentioned in beginning defined as:

(iii) $|xy|=|x||y|$, where $|x|=\sqrt{x^2_0 + x^2_1 +...+x^2_{n-1}}$

Then following statements are equivalent:

(a) $x^2=-|x|^2 \iff$ (b) scalar product of $\mathbf x$ and $e_0$ is $0$.

What I concluded so far:

(1) from right to left premise is equivalent to $x_0=0$.

(2) from left to right premise is equivalent to $$\mathbf{xx}=\mathbf x^2=\langle a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\rangle^T=-|x|^2e_0=\langle-|x|^2,0,\dots,0\rangle^T,$$ and therefore $a_0=-|x|^2$.

However now I'm at loss of how to continue. How will this statement help us to prove that square of imaginary unit is equal to $-1$? It is a weaker version of statement above, as imaginary unit equals $e_i, i=\{1,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Everything before "Finally my question" can be stated as "Let $e_0$ be the multiplicative identity of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. You don't need to enumerate standard conventions and definitions in elementary linear algebra. Moreover, the multiplicative identity of a vector space is a scalar, not a vector that is part of the space's basis as your definition of $e_0$ seems to suggest.

Comment: Quaternions are **not** commutative, hence not a field. The word you want is "skew-field" or "division ring".

Comment: In defining the inner product, you write the sum first from $0$ to $n-1,$ then from $1$ to $n.$ A vector with all $0$ entries cannot be a basis vector, so it makes no sense to say $e_0$ is all $0$s, but perhaps this is a result of the confusion over whether to count from $0$ to $n-1$ or from $1$ to $n.$

Comment: Your approach seems to imply that you could build a system with any number of imaginary units you want, for example there could be exactly two, or exactly four. From what I understand of quaternions, this doesn't work.

Comment: @Brian Hi, unfortunately your comment makes little to no sense to me. Now in definition of quaternions, there is explicitly stated that {1,i,j,k} is a basis. Now this basis can be constructed as mentioned above or not? If e$_0$ doesn't equal to 4x1 vector, how should I interpret the (b) statement? That is are you trying to say that scalar product of x and e$_0$ is equal to x$_1$ + x$_2$ + x$_3$ since x is vector 3x1?

Comment: @Somos Most definitely, that was bad on my part. That is also part of the quaternion construction, that we don't have commutativity in relation to multiplication.

Comment: @Brian and e$_0$ is equal to vector 3x1 as (1,1,1)$^T$?

Comment: How is one to interpret “$x^2 = -|x|^2$“? $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and your multiplication is defined $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. So the left hand side is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But $|x|\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, so the right hand side is a nonpositive real number. How is it that you have an equality between an $n$-vector and a nonpositive real?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well since I have multiplicative one I can use it to describe −|x|$^2$ as ⟨−|x|$^2$,0,…,0⟩$^T$. That's how I understand it and that's all the statement of the excercise gives us.

Answer (score 2):

There are several equally valid ways to describe the system of quaternions. One way is to work with couples where one part is a real number and the other part is a vector in $\,\mathbb{R}^3.\,$
Thus, let $\, e_0 := \bf{1}\,$ be the real unit and $\,e_1 := (1,0,0) = \bf{i},\,$ $e_2 := (0,1,0) = \bf{j},\,$  and $\,e_3 := (0,0,1) = \bf{k}\,$ be the three vector units. At this point, the construction is easy, except for product of two vectors. There are **two** products of vectors. One is the scalar or dot product. The other is the vector or cross product. Introduce the quaternion product of
two vectors by
$\, {\bf u \, v} := {\bf -u\cdot v} + 
{\bf u \times v}\,$
with a real and a vector part.

If we restrict to vectors with only one quaternion unit, then we essentially have a version of complex numbers. Hamilton knew that he had to have
$\, {\bf i}^2 = {\bf j}^2 = {\bf k}^2 = -1\,$ for this reason. What **was** surprising to him was that for a consistent system he had to require that
$\, {\bf k} = {\bf i\, j} = - {\bf j\,i}.\,$
The sign change is reflected in the skew
commutativity of the vector cross product.